# Silverlight version not display in Listbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, registry

Can anyone help me what's the problem.

When I run it, it will show a blank Listbox how can I want to display. Only silver light version.

Thank you.

```
private void GetSilverLightInstall()
{
    string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight\Version";

    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
    {
        foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
            {
                 lsitBox1.Items.Add(sk.GetValue("DisplayName"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system `Version` is a string value, not a key. Hence the following works for me:

```
var keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight";

using (var regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName))
{
    var version = regKey.GetValue("Version") as string;

    Debug.WriteLine(version);
}
```